# SSRS report returns less rows than the stored procedure it calls

Tags: stored-procedures, reporting-services

I have created a stored procedure that gathers data from 3 different tables based on the year. When I run the stored procedure it returns 22 rows consistently. I then created an SSRS report from that stored procedure (VS 2017). When I run the SSRS report I only get 18 records.

The SSRS report is incredibly simple, it's just a table that displays the data. I double checked and everything is set to show. The parameter is being passed correctly (if no parameter is passed, no rows are returned) when I look at the report server and there are no errors on the report server. In looking at the report server I can see that it's only returning 18 rows, not the 22 it should be.

I also turned Ansi Warnings off just in case.

The rows that aren't showing do have a null in one field (by design) but to test it I put a value in there and they still aren't being returned.

Lastly I recreated the report, just in case there was something in the original report causing this.

I am looking for ideas of where else to look.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Things to check. 1. Click the refresh button on the report control toolbar to make sure you are not seeing a locally cached copy of the data (or delete the .rdldata file). 2. Open the query designer for the dataset and execute the query from there, see how many records are returned. 3. Make sure the datasource is pointing the the correct server/database.

Comment: Ai Alan I wasn't able to see a refresh button nor was there a .rdldata for that file so I deleted the rdl in the debug folder and removed the file that was on the report server. When I run it from the query designer it returns the same number of rows. The datasource is pointing to the correct server.

Comment: The refresh button is normally to the right of the page controls. When you say "the same number of rows". Do you mean the incorrect number of rows?

Comment: Sorry, yes, that is correct, it still only returns 18 rows not the 22 that I expect.

Comment: I figured it out. Our database uses different "sites" and even though I was setting the site, it wasn't passing it through. Thanks for your help!

Comment: glad you got it sorted.